# Ionic 4 plugin - Object is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ionic 4 google plus plugin to log in with google, but when I call :

```
    googleLogin(){
    this.nativeGoogleLogin();
    }

  async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('trying to log in with google');
    const creds = {
      'webClientId': '125618127989-slbv15359v8g76elj0664agipfedc5cn.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'offline': true,
      'scopes': 'profile email'
    }
    try {
       await this.googlePlus.login(creds).then(res => console.log(res)) // This line gets error

    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

I get error :

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at GooglePlus.login (index.js:27)
>       at BuyerLoginPage. (buyer-login.ts:109)
>       at step (buyer-login.module.ts:26)
>       at Object.next (buyer-login.module.ts:26)
>       at buyer-login.module.ts:26
>       at new t (polyfills.js:3)
>       at webpackJsonp.555.__awaiter (buyer-login.module.ts:26)
>       at BuyerLoginPage.webpackJsonp.555.BuyerLoginPage.nativeGoogleLogin
>   (buyer-login.ts:101)
>       at BuyerLoginPage.webpackJsonp.555.BuyerLoginPage.googleLogin (buyer-login.ts:117)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (BuyerLoginPage.html:141)

**I mean, it isn't even firing cordova plugin, it's just error which says nothing to me. Anyone help ?**

Comment: Could you please provide some extra information?  Have you installed both plugin + npm package? Have you done the import in app.module.ts & in your component?

Comment: Yes I did all of these things.